# Get The selected cartItem using MVC Model

Tags: c#, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view model which holds the available products and after i show them in a view i have to get the particular item which he clicks on Add to Cart

My Action

```
      public ActionResult Test1()
       {
        DUPVM obj = new DUPVM();
        MembersipEntities Entity = new MembersipEntities();
        obj.test = Entity.Dups.ToList();
        return View(obj);
       }

       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test1(Dup model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
```

and the viewmodel

```
public class DUPVM
    {
        public IEnumerable<Dup> test { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my view i will display the all products available by looping through them

```
 @model MVC4.Models.DUPVM
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test1", "PDF", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var item in Model.test)
    {


        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.ID)
        <br>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Rate)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.AgentID)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => item.ID)
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
        <br>
    }
}
```

Then If a user clicks on Add to cart then i want to pass all details of that products to controller using model. But i am not able to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change your view to create the `form` inside the loop. This way you are getting a discrete form with only the values you require.

```
@model MVC4.Models.DUPVM
foreach (var item in Model.test)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Test1", "PDF", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.ID)
        <br>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Rate)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.AgentID)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => item.ID)
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
        <br>
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey a small query how do i get the value of Rate in the controller as i its being used as DisplayFor  ? i am getting ID  for this back again in controller @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => item.ID) but not for @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Rate)

Comment: You could add `@Html.HiddenFor(modelitem => item.Rate)`

Comment: Yeah that came into mind but if i need to got 3-4 values back to the contrller. Will it be the same process or any alternative

Comment: Personally I wouldn't pass anything back other than the `ID` anyway. The rest should come from the database as it's all linked.

Answer (score 1):

Your view is strongly-typed to the `DUPVM` class but your controller action is expecting a single `Dup`.  The default behaviour of the form Razor helpers is to post the model back in the same format it was accepted.

To get this to work you will need to create a partial view for each item, strongly type that partial view to a `Dup` (not a DUPVM) and either write some javascript that posts your selected item to the controller, or have a seperate form for each item.

You partial view might look something like this

```
@model MVC4.Models.Dup
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test1", "PDF", FormMethod.Post))
{
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ID)
        <br>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Rate)
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AgentID)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ID)
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
        <br>
}
```

And your main view like this:

```
@model MVC4.Models.DUPVM
@foreach (var item in Model.test)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_YourPartialView", item);
}
```